# Libreoffice has black UI panels

Tags: lubuntu, 15.10, libreoffice

In my Lubuntu 15.10, all Libreoffice applications (well, I've tried Write, Calc and Impress) have a black UI:

[image: screenshot]

I've tried updating, but it didn't help. I've tried searching through LO settings, but besides the pain in the ass of navigating through it, I didn't see anything unusual.

I'm not sure what to try next.

Comment: Maybe try updating to 16.04? Also, was LO working previously, and then this suddenly happened? Or was it like this the first time you ran LO on this installation?

Comment: I will update to 16.04 lts, but not in a few weeks (15.10 should have support for another few months at least). It's not my computer, but a relative's, so I don't have non-stop access to it. I think it worked before, but tbh, it's been a while and I wasn't using it much (it's not a fresh LO install. It was there basically since I installed it last autumn). I just did a normal update (it's been a while).

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt purge libreoffice && sudo apt install libreoffice` ?

Comment: Not yet, I might try it next time I will have access to that pc.

Answer (score 1):

Open LibreOffice Writer then go to **Tools>Options>Application Colors**.
Make sure everything is set to automatic.

[image: Screenshot]

If this doesn't work then try reinstalling it.

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```